# How to count NULL inside CASE?

Tags: sql-server

**What is the best way to count `NULL` values inside `case`?**

Using a joined table - I am trying to count the values of the column `P.ID` (from the joined table), and to categorize the counted values into a new column  **via** `case`.

For example:

- when count 0 - display 'none'
- when count 1-2 - display 'few'.
- when count 3-5 - display 'medium
- when count 5+ - display 'many'

However, since some of the values received from the join are null - I cannot count them.

What changes should I do to my query in order to refer every `NULL` as 0?

```
SELECT 
    U.Mail, 
    COUNT(P.ID) AS PostCount, 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(P.ID) = 0 THEN'none' --doesn't work
        WHEN COUNT(P.ID) <= 2 THEN 'few'
        WHEN COUNT(P.ID) <= 5 THEN 'medium'
        ELSE 'many'
    END AS PostCountCategory
FROM
    Users U 
LEFT JOIN 
    Tag T ON U.Mail = T.Mail
LEFT JOIN 
    Post P on T.IDPost = P.ID
GROUP BY U.Mail;
```

Comment: Add a `coalesce`?

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? I ran your query and the result seems ok. Maybe you should add the DDL and some sample data to show what is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very clear on your question however you can alter your code as below for your null question:

```
select U.Mail, count(isnull(P.ID, 0)) as PostCount, 
    case 
        when count(P.ID) = 0 then 'none' --doesn't work
        when (count(P.ID) <= 2 and count(P.ID) > 0) then 'few'
        when (count(P.ID) <= 5 and count(P.ID) > 2 )then 'medium'
        else 'many'
    end PostCountCategory
from Users U 
left join Tag T on U.Mail = T.Mail
left join Post P on T.IDPost = P.ID
group by U.Mail
```

Alternatively you can use `count(isnull(P.ID, 0))` inside your case statement. Hope this helps.

As suggested by [Mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio), you may use `coalesce` also instead of `isnull`.

Comment: Hi!
There's a missing bracket on `when count(P.ID) <= 5 and count(P.ID) > 2 )then 'medium'` and by adding `count(isnull(P.ID, 0))` it is now counting the nulls. the result doesn't seem right. In fact the resultset from her query seems ok.

Comment: @Ronaldo Thank you for pointing out about parenthesis, fixed it.